# UIKit: CGAffineTransforms and Composited Animations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit

I've noticed that when animating things in UIKit, certain types of animations can be composited using standard block-based animations while others cannot. For instance, view.transform interferes with view.frame, but not with view.center. Are these things documented anywhere?

On a related note, because of these compositing issues, I've often resorted to animating mainly using CGAffineTransforms, since they can be composited very easily. Is this a good idea? It seems that applying a transform is different under the hood than simply changing the frame, so I'm not sure if I should be using them to permanently move a view or change its size. Do CGAffineTransforms and view.frame-related changes overlap at all?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if they are documented together somewhere (or even what the other issues might be), but there is a very clear, very large warning that the frame property of UIView is undefined if the transform matrix isn't the identity in UIView's docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's Apple's stance on this:

> You typically modify the transform property of a view when you want to
>   implement animations. For example, you could use this property to
>   create an animation of your view rotating around its center point. You
>   would not use this property to make permanent changes to your view,
>   such as modifying its position or size a view within its superview’s
>   coordinate space. For that type of change, you should modify the frame
>   rectangle of your view instead.

Source: [View Programming Guide for iOS, View and Window Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)

(I suppose one exception would be permanently rotated views, which would be impossible to accomplish with frame modifications.)

I've also determined that CGAffineTransforms appear to modify the underlying rendered image of a view, not its content, so (for example) applying a CGAffineTransformScale is fundamentally different from expanding the frame. I'm not sure if this is necessarily true, or if it depends on contentMode/other factors.

I'm still not entirely clear on how the frame, bounds, and transform of a view interact. You can, for example, set the frame of a view after applying a rotation, and it'll be relative to the rotated view, whereas modifying the bounds will apply the transformation to the view pre-rotation (IIRC).